# Update key value in array of objects php

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

I have an array of objects where the reference is not the same as the code_cip.

```
Array ( 
[9921279] => lignecatalogue Object ( [id] => 3013181 [reference] => 9921279 [commentaire] => [code_cip] => 9884064 )
[9884064] => lignecatalogue Object ( [id] => 3013193 [reference] => 9884064 [commentaire] => [code_cip] => 9884064 )
)
```

What i am trying to accomplish is to update only the `[reference] => 9921279` on the first item to `[reference] => 9884064`. The `[reference]` will be updated only if it is not equal to its code_cip. So far i am stuck on the code below.

```
$arrLigneCats = getAllCat(); //returns above array

foreach($arrLigneCats as $ligneCat) {
    if ($ligneCat->code_cip != $ligneCat->reference) {
        $reference = $ligneCat->reference;
    } else {
        $reference = $ligneCat->code_cip;
    }
}
```

Anyone has any idea of how to replace the key without the removing the entire line?

Comment: Problem! Should you also be amending the key as well as that seems to match the `reference`

Comment: Pass the `$ligneCat` by reference, like this `foreach($arrLigneCats as &$ligneCat) {`

Comment: Then `$ligneCat->reference = $ligneCat->code_cip;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, the problem is that **$reference** is just a variable, what you have to change is the **reference property** of the object. So it will be:

```
$arrLigneCats = getAllCat(); //returns above array

foreach($arrLigneCats as $ligneCat) {
    if ($ligneCat->code_cip != $ligneCat->reference) {
        $ligneCat->reference = $ligneCat->code_cip;
    }
}
```

Does it answer your question?